# How Python QT two windows<based on .ui file> swtich

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt5, qt-designer

I create a main window use QT ui window file and
I want to click menu pop another ui window. this is second window,
and after close, the main window will get focus and get data from second window.

How can i do this?

I search internet and find convert ui file to py file, use as class.
Actually i will change window, in QT designer, So i down't want change to py file.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Use a QDialog, so that you can call its `exec()` method, which returns only when the dialog is closed, and then you can get all necessary data from the dialog UI. If you need further help, provide a valid [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch between two windows based on `.ui` files in a PyQt application without converting the `.ui` files to `.py` files, you can use the `uic` module to load the `.ui` files dynamically. This way, you can easily make changes in Qt Designer and see them reflected in your application without needing to regenerate Python files.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys

def open_second_window():
    second_window.show()
    data_from_second_window = second_window.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, 'lineEdit')
    # Do something with data_from_second_window if needed

def close_second_window():
    # Get data from second_window if needed
    second_window.hide()
    main_window.show()

app = QApplication([])

main_window = uic.loadUi("main_window.ui")
second_window = uic.loadUi("second_window.ui")

# Connect menu action to open the second window
main_window.actionOpenSecondWindow.triggered.connect(open_second_window)

# Connect a button in the second window to close it and return to the main window
second_window.pushButton.clicked.connect(close_second_window)

main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```